# Save excel from .Net windows service/Powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, excel-2010

I am in a tricky situation from last few days. We have an existing Win 2003 server and are moving over to Win 2008. I have setup new Win 2008 server and facing one problem.

Current server has

Windown service --calls-> .Net exe --calls-> powershell script --calls-> excel introp's workbook.SaveAs()

Everything works fine with this. .net version is 4.0, powershell version is 2.0, MS Office version is 2007.

On the new server, they couldnt install office 2007 so had to settle for office 2010. On the new server, the above chain of events leads to an error in workbook.SaveAs():

*Exception calling "SaveAs" with "1" argument(s): "SaveAs method of Workbook class failed"
Runtime exception: SaveAs: Exception calling "SaveAs" with "1" argument(s): "SaveAs method of Workbook class failed" At line:180 char:18 + $workbook.SaveAs <<<< ("$filepath"*)

On the same server, if I skip windows service and directly call 
.net exe --calls-> powershell --calls-> excel introp's workbook.SaveAs()
everything works fine.

Hope I managed to explain the problem. Not sure what is causing this. I have checked things such as permission for the accout on folder where excel is trying to save.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Cant believe I spent three days on this and the solution is so silly!!

Thanks a tonn to the person who posted this:

http://www.techdecode.com/wp/?p=58

(From the link above)
・Windows 2008 Server x64

Please make this folder

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop

・Windows 2008 Server x86

Please make this folder.

C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop

Frustrating, but fixed!